# Read flat file line by line using smooks

Tags: smooks

I have a flat file as input. I need to read the flat file line by line using Smooks. 
Can anyone please give me suggestions or sample code how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is Smooks Config file (SmooksConfig_ForFlatFile.xml).

here is Input File  (input-messages.txt)
charles             moulliard           Male   43BE
maxence             dewil               Male   30NL
eleonor             moulliard           Female 12AD

Here is the java code:
smooks  = new Smooks("SmooksConfig_ForFlatFile.xml");

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("FlatFile_Output.xml");
        smooks.filterSource(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("input-message.txt")), new StreamResult(fos));
```

Comment: Content of SmooksConfig file  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:fl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/fixed-length-1.3.xsd">
<!--    Configure the Fixed length to parse the message into a stream of SAX events.    -->    
 <fl:reader fields="firstname[18],middlename[2],lastname[20],gender[6],age[3],country[2]" indent="true">
 </fl:reader>
</smooks-resource-list>

Comment: Contents of input-message.txt charles             moulliard           Male   43BE
maxence             dewil               Male   30NL
eleonor             moulliard           Female 12AD